# Is this a jQuery or PHP issue

Tags: php

I have created a jsfiddle for the following problem. I have tried to recreate it but it is hard because the data is being displayed server-side with PHP from a MySQL database.

I have a table and I am trying to pass the clicked `<td>` content into my modal box. If it doesn't have any, the modal box should appear with the user id but the input boxes are empty.

For some reason, the user id changes fine but the start time and end time inputs don't! Also, when I inspect the element it displays 8 - 5 for all the users? Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

php code with the click + data params

```
        for($dow = 0; $dow <= 6; $dow++) {
            ?><td class="js-clickable" data-user_id="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" data-start_time="<?php echo $row['st']; ?>" data-end_time="<?php echo $row['et']; ?>"<?php
                if (array_key_exists($dow, $list)) {
                    foreach ($list[$dow] as $row) {
                        if ($row['user_id'] == $user_id) {
                            echo date("H:i", strtotime($row['st'])) . " - " . date("H:i", strtotime($row['et']));
```

Comment: Reproducing the problem in a jsfiddle indicates that the problem is not PHP-related.

Comment: @showdev i dont think so, because in the markup,the `data-end_time` and `data-start_time` for Michael is shown as `data-end_time="2015-03-27 17:30:00" data-start_time="2015-03-27 08:30:00"`. so i think the issue is with your php code.

Comment: Those should be ok, start time is before end time, no?

Comment: @Lal Yes, but I am not sure if it's because of the `data-param` in the php. That's why it's hard to recreate the problem I am having because the table `<td>` is being filled from a database.

Comment: may be the values fetched from the database is not correct..check it once more..your jquery has no errors at all.its working fine..

Comment: @Lal True. My logic was flawed. The jsfiddle is based on output generated by PHP.

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as accepted if i add one?

Comment: Also, when I inspect the element of the generated <td> it seems to show Kate's 8-5 for all of their data-params except John?

Comment: I have added that as my answer.Kindly mark it as accepted if that helped you.

Comment: PS - Your closing </form> tag should be after the </div> that is above it in your HTML.

Comment: @ewjfhweufh, I have added an answer that resolves the issues in your PHP code. Please comment on that answer if you need more help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've identified the issues with your PHP code that caused the data to be incorrectly populated in the table.

The main issue was to do with bad logic in the section that writes the  tags. For example, the $row variable used to write the data attributes was entirely different from the $row variable used to write the contents of the TD.  Also, you were writing the data attributes of the first TD tag before even looking for the schedule for that user.  I revamped the code in that section so that the full TD tag is written in two areas, either with scheduled data, or without.  The code is still pretty messy, but at least now it works.  Also, on line 57 of the code in the pastebin you posted had a misplaced quote between the php closing tag (?>).  It was:  ?">  It should be:  ?>"

A couple of smaller observations:
 - Bootstrap CSS was linked twice (one local, one remote). Not part of the issue, just an observation.
 - The closing tag for the form and the surrounding div were in the wrong order. Close the form before the div.

Here is the working code to correctly populate the data attributes and content of the table:

```
// Code removed at request of OP.
```

Comment: Also, I had the header tags etc fine in my document, I must have copy and pasted it wrong in the pastebin haha but thanks for pointing out the faults with my code it's nice to learn, otherwise I would've continued doing it like that!

Comment: How about I just leave the code of the main loop and strip everything else, is that cool?

Comment: Yeah that's great! @BenjaminRay

Comment: Thank you for everything! @BenjaminRay

Comment: @ewjfhweufh I saw your request to delete the code - do you still want me to do that?

Comment: Hi, sorry, yes - if that is possible, I wasn't sure if you had seen it. Sorry for all the hassle

Comment: Code removed as requested.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `PHP` code as the `HTML` markup shown in the fiddle clearly shows that the `data-end_time` and `data-start_time` for Michael is shown as `data-end_time="2015-03-27 17:30:00" data-start_time="2015-03-27 08:30:00"`.

There might be some error in the values fetched from the database. Make sure that you retrieve the values from the database correctly.

The jquery that you have written works perfectly in this case.

Comment: It does retrieve the values correctly. The data type values for the fields in the database are correct also.

Comment: But when you look at the html code, you can see that the values for the times are not correct while the value for `user_id` is  correct.

Comment: Lal is correct - jQuery is correctly picking up the data attributes that appear in the <td> tags.  E.g. Michael's shift for every TD beside his name is 2015/03/27 from 8:30 to 17:30.  That's what is displaying in the modal window as well.

Comment: It displays the values in the HTML table correctly. Visually I can see that Kate has 8-5 and nothing else. In the mark-up however it puts 8-5 as data param for all of them when it should be for just that one `<td>` cell.

Comment: No. For john the data params are empty.

Comment: @BenjaminRay Yes, that is how I want it to be displayed. But why is it doing that for all of them? That is my question! Michael doesn't have any. Also, there aren't any in the database.

Comment: how are you populating the values for the data params?

Comment: Yes, the values in the <td> content may be correct, but the values in data-start_time and data-end_time do not match what is in the <td> content. And the jQuery is getting its information from those values.
For example, Michael has no shifts visible, but this data is attached to all three days:  
data-end_time="2015-03-27 17:30:00" data-start_time="2015-03-27 08:30:00"

Comment: That's why i said some mistake with the php code..by the way how are you populating the data params?

Comment: clearly mistake with php as your `$row['start_time'];` and `$row['end_time'];` is not getting the right values.

Comment: Try moving `?><td class="js-clickable" data-user_id="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" data-start_time="<?php echo $row['start_time']; ?>" data-end_time="<?php echo $row['end_time']; ?>"<?php` to inside of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: because you are assigning `$list[$dow]` to `$row` in the foreach loop and for the first time it'll certainly be empty and for the second time it'll be the previous value and so on.

Comment: What are the chances of you getting us a copy of all of the current code, as well as the related data for those users and schedules from the database?  Sure most of us could solve this almost immediately if we were able to sit down at your IDE, so let us recreate it in our IDE and it might do the job.

Comment: Ok - might take me until later today to get to it, but I will.

Comment: @BenjaminRay Hello, have you had the chance to look at it?

Comment: Will be able to in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

This is a PHP issue, because it was written at the PHP.

Now why it happens like that may be at `date("H:i", strtotime($row['start_time']))` and I think the expected value(`$row['start_time']` and `$row['end_time']`) don't return a expected string to the `strtotime` function.

Check your code at this block and check how it is returned.

```
if ($row['user_id'] == $user_id) {
    echo date("H:i", strtotime($row['start_time'])) . " - " . date("H:i", strtotime($row['end_time']));
}
```

I hope I've helped ya.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by not "returning a expected string"

Comment: No @ewjfhweufh that block of code is right as the values are correctly displayed in the table.